# Issue using open() in python with a linux global variable

Tags: python, linux, scripting, nmap

I trying to open and read a file with open() in python, with the global variable $USER in Linux, but the program stops in the 2 line. I want to believe that the problem is in the open() function because I use $USER in the 1 line and all is ok:

```
os.system("/usr/bin/nmap {target} -oN /home/$USER/.nmap_diff/scan{today}.txt")
scantxt = open("/home/$USER/.nmap_diff/scan{today}.txt","rb")
```

The output is:

```
File "diffscanner.py", line 92, in scanner
  scantxt = open("/home/$USER/.nmap_diff/scan{}.txt".format(today),"rb")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/$USER/.nmap_diff/scan2021-07-10.txt'
```

The output said the scan2021-07-10.txt has not found, but it really exist:
[scan2021-07-10.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gPBq.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system) executes the command(passed as string) in a **subshell**. That means, the command will have access to the Linux's environment variables, `USER` in your case.

On the other hand, `open` expects a [path-like](https://docs.python.org/3.8/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) object such as a path string. The string is read as it is and not evaluated to replace `USER`(or any other environment variable) with actual values. If you want to use env var, use `os.environ`

```
import os

USER = os.environ['USER']

scantxt = open(f"/home/{USER}/.nmap_diff/scan{today}.txt","rb")
```

Comment: I think line 3 should be `USER = os.environ["USER"]`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$USER` is being interpreted as a literal string by `open`, not as an environment variable. To expand environment variables in the string, use [os.path.expandvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars).

```
os.system(f"/usr/bin/nmap {target} -oN /home/$USER/.nmap_diff/scan{today}.txt")
result_path = os.path.expandvars(f"/home/$USER/.nmap_diff/scan{today}.txt")
with open(result_path, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    scantxt = f.read()
```

By the way, it also looks like the strings in your question were meant to be [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), but were missing the `f` prefixes. I have added them in my answer.

Also, I am assuming that you want the scan results as a string, so I have added the code for that as well. (It seems that nmap doesn't usually include any non-ascii characters in its output for the `-oN` option, but I am specifying the encoding as UTF-8 in case support for UTF-8 characters is added in a future version.)